# Magento how to show menus in top menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am really newbie to Magento. I have this piece of code to show top menus.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="level0 first homelink"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
        <?php if($_menu): ?>
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $additionalLink = themeOptions('additionalLink'); ?>
        <?php $additionalLinkUrl = themeOptions('additionalLinkUrl'); ?>
        <?php if($additionalLinkUrl && $additionalLink): ?>
            <li class="level0 clearence"><a href="<?php echo $additionalLinkUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $additionalLink ?>"><span><?php echo $additionalLink ?></span></a></li>
        <?php endif ?>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now this is showing only Home as menu. I want to show other menus like about us,contacts,
and there will be also some categories with sub categories. I want my menu should look like this
http://8theme.com/demo/decostore/ . So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have use the Top Menu (already created) in theme Folder /template/page/html/topMenu.phtml file

here includes the Categories and also the Custome url set using with blocks